# How do I link JSON files within AJAX with Django?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I have a Django app and within it I'm using a template HTML page that utilizes a Javascript library called Cytoscape (allows you to create graphs with nodes and edges).

I have everything set up with regards to templates and static files (the CSS and basic JS functions are working), however the one thing I'm having issues with is the Ajax functions within my main javascript file. These Ajax functions are responsible for displaying the graphs from JSON files (see code below as to how), and they work fine locally without Django. But as soon as I try to incorporate the server-side implementation, the functions can no longer read these files and I don't know how to fix this.

I've attempted to copy over the JSON files into various directories (but I'm still running into a 404 not found error: "Not found filldata/undefined.json", (where filldata is my app) presumably because this URL has not been set up on the server-side.

```
function onUpload() {

    var filename = $('input[type=file]').val().split('\\').pop();

    var layoutPadding = 50;
    var aniDur = 500;
    var easing = 'linear';

    var cy;


    if (upload_true) {
        var graphP = $.ajax({
            url: filename,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json'
        });

        var styleP = $.ajax({
            url: './style.cycss', // wine-and-cheese-style.cycss
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'text'
        });
    } else {
        var graphP = $.ajax({
            url: './undefined.json',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json'
        });

        // also get style via ajax
        var styleP = $.ajax({
            url: './style.cycss',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'text'
        });
    }
```

The goal here is to be able to upload JSON files on my web page and link the .cycss (css file specific to Cytoscape) within Django to run my page on the server-side. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Django is a web server. You cannot access files like `./style.cycss` etc. You need to set up a static URL, host your files there and use that URL in your code. you can check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/) about hosting static files. you need to store your JSON in a similar way and use it with a URL.

Comment: How would I set up the appropriate URL for these files? Do I need to add separate views for each JSON file, and set up each URL in the urls.py? I apologize if I'm asking the wrong questions, the documentation doesn't seem to go too in depth with this

Comment: If you have a static folder and static URL configured, you can place the JSON files there and you can access like `static_url/first.json`, `static_url/second.json` etc.